# How to check if SEO keyword already exist when edit product/category - Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

When i edit product/category how can i check if seo keyword already exist in database ? i need it for custom use

Comment: which opencart version did you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to check by programmatically then you can use following function for check, if SEO is exist or not. this will work in all version.

```
function check_seo($keyword = ''){
    if(version_compare(VERSION, '3.0.0.0', '<')){ // below 3.0.0.0 version
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `keyword` LIKE '" . $this->db->escape($keyword)."'";
    }else{
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE `keyword` LIKE '" . $this->db->escape($keyword)."'";
    }
    $found =  $this->db->query($SQL." LIMIT 1")->num_rows;

    if($found){
        // SEO already exists
    }else{
        // You can use this $keyword for SEO
    }
}
```

like if you want to check only for `mac` category SEO then check below Query and image,

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM `oc_url_alias` WHERE `query` LIKE 'category_id=%' AND `keyword` LIKE 'mac'
```

[image]

Comment: this is little bit confuse me , i dont think this will work SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias SET query LIKE

Comment: if you only work with category then you have to add that in where condition !

Comment: this wont work when you edit category/product as i required

Comment: @lvan so, how you exactly you want,  can you please edit your question with more details of your requirement !

Comment: all details are there no need to edit "When i edit product/category how can i check if seo keyword already exist in database" i post the answer

Comment: that's what my ans ! this will work with all version.

Comment: yes i will accept your answer my question was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what version of OpenCart do you use. In OpenCart 3 when you try to save SEO URL that already exist - you will receive a message 
[image]

Although there is a place, where yo can search across all OpenCart SEO URLs. You will find it in *Design - SEO URL*
[image]

Comment: the question was how i can do it ? i mean programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Checking for duplicate SEO

Controller

```
$url_alias_info = $this->model_catalog_url_alias->getUrlAlias($this->request->post['keyword']);

if ($url_alias_info && isset($this->request->post['category_id']) && $url_alias_info['query'] != 'category_id=' . $this->request->post['category_id']) {
 $json['error'] = 'SEO exist';
}
```

Model

```
public function getUrlAlias($keyword) {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($keyword) . "'");

  return $query->row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can solve this issue with simple steps.**

-> Go to your opencart database and find "oc_seo_url" table open it.

-> search that records which are have keyword field null/empty

-> delete that records

**You can see in the picture bellow.**

[image]